# Definiteness of quadratic form by completing the square

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I want to check my thinking here.
We're asked to determine the definiteness of the matrix

$   \begin{pmatrix}
      3 & -1 & 1\\\ -1 & 1 & 2\\ 1 & 2 & 9
    \end{pmatrix}  $

We can write down the quadratic form as:

$3x_1^2  - 2 x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 + 4 x_2 x_3 + 6x_3^2 + 2 x_1 x_3 $

So by completing the square we arrive at

$(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (x_2 + 2x_3)^2 + (x_1 + x_3)^2  + x_1^2 - x_2^2 + x_3^2 $

But now it seems quite difficult to determine the definiteness, how would this usually be done?

Answer (score 2):

There is a quick way to check positive definiteness called Sylvester's criterion which states that a matrix is positive definite if and only if the upper-left hand matrices have positive determinant, i.e.

Applying it to your matrix:

$\begin{vmatrix} 3 \end{vmatrix} >0; \begin{vmatrix} 3 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{vmatrix} = 3 -1 = 2>0; \begin{vmatrix} 3 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 9 \end{vmatrix} = 15-11-3 = 1 > 0$

Therefore your matrix is positive definite.

Comment: Oops, I do indeed. I've edited my comment.

Answer (score 1):

fairly understandable algorithm for completing  the square. Without finding the eigenvalues, given a symmetric matrix $H,$   find a nonsingular matrix $P$   such that $D=P^THP$  is diagonal. Then Sylvester's Law of Inertia says the diagonal elements of $D$ have the same $\pm$ signs as the eigenvalues.

I put the outcome first...

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Algorithm discussed at [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 26 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Answer (score 0):

To the other answers I'll add for completeness a "completing the square" answer.
\begin{align*}
  3x_1^2 -2x_1x_2 +x_2^2 + 4x_2x_3 + 6x_3^2 + 2x_1x_3
       &= 3(x_1 - x_2/3 + x_3/3)^2 +\frac23 x_2^2 + \frac{14}3x_2x_3 + \frac{26}3x_3^2 \\
       &= 3(x_1 - x_2/3 + x_3/3)^2 + \frac23(x_2 + 7x_3/2)^2 +\frac12x_3^2,
\end{align*}
which is clearly positive definite. The key difference from your completion of the square is that I've fixed the $x_1x_2$ and $x_1x_3$ cross terms with the first square.